# Docker for Magento 2 Development

Tags: magento, docker-compose

**Original Post**:
Install Magento 2! Before copying and pasting the command shown below into the Docker terminal
Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
url : https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento-2-tutorials/docker-magento-2-development/#install-docker

**Additional notes from the comment**:
After this command : php bin/magento setup:install \ --admin-firstname=John \ --admin-lastname=Doe \ --admin-email=johndoe@example.com \ --admin-user=admin \ --admin-password='SomePassword123' \ --base-url=local.domain.com \ --base-url-secure=local.domain.com \ --backend-frontname=admin \ --db-host=mysql \ --db-name=magento \ --db-user=root \ --db-password=root \ --use-rewrites=1 \ --language=en_US \ --currency=USD \ --timezone=America/New_York \ --use-secure-admin=1 \ --admin-use-security-key=1 \ --session-save=files \ --use-sample-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-you must have a php version 7 imperatively
2-php bin/magento sampledata:deploy (recommended)
3 -Finally, Let’s Install Magento 2! (Install Magento 2! Before copying and pasting the command shown below into the Docker terminal ) (step 4)
you have to do this step (step 4 ) after :
docker exec -it web bash and cd /app

worked --> OK